# Gitlab workflow and configuration for users

Tags: git, gitlab

### Context / Information

I installed gitlab on ubuntu 12.04 as described on this official page:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/installation.md

After I installed, I was able to access the web interface at `http://machine_ip:3000` with the credentials:

admin@local.host

5iveL!fe

On my machine, I have the following users: 
- git (that was set with no password as in the tutorial)
- gitlab (set auto as in the tutorial)
- my_username (the normal user used by me as root)

In the web interface of gitlab, when requested, I generated a public rsa key on my_username and pasted it there.

I then proceeded to create a repository in /home/my_username/test with git init and git remote add origin as in the tutorial. When I'm trying to push my commit, I get the following error:

```
To git@localhost:test.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@localhost:test.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm telling you all this to have a better understanding of what I've tried to achieve and what error messages I'm getting.

### The problem

On a developer's machine, I installed putty, pageant and puttygen and msysgit. I generated a key that was associated with a new user in gitlab's interface. Also, I set GIT_SSH to use plink in order to have msysgit use pageant (which is serving the key for connection).

I am able to connect to git@machine_ip using no passwords, so the key is added to authorized_keys in git.

However, when I try to clone the repository with source location git@machine_ip:test.git I'm getting the following error message:

```
fatal: 'test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I don't know what I'm getting wrong here. Am I supposed to do something different (creating a new project, setting a repository differently, adding a new user and their key in gitlab) etc.

Can you please provide some help?

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?